# Upload file to Alfresco in ProcessMaker

Tags: alfresco, processmaker

I am trying out a mashup of Alfresco and ProcessMaker. I intend to use Alfresco's document management capabilities over ProcessMaker.

Here is the scenario:

A user fills up a form in ProcessMaker and a file is uploaded in Alfresco.

I followed the wiki in [this](http://wiki.processmaker.com/index.php/Alfresco_V_4.0#Upload_file.2Fdocument_in_Alfresco_Repository_.28uploadDoc.29) link. The problem is that, my result variable is always false. I also checked my input. I am able to access Alfresco via the address I provided, but it still does not work. I also ensured that the file exists in my directory.

Is there a way I can check (probably from logs or console) the error being returned by Alfresco or ProcessMaker so I can continue?

- Alfresco is installed in a Japanese version of Windows 7.
- Alfresco version is 4.2.c.
- Process Maker version is 2.0.45.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have no experience with ProcessMaker, but here's a couple of things you can try to investigate your issue:

- inspect the network traffic between ProcessMaker and Alfresco (e.g. with [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/)) to see if there's any hint available in the HTTP responses from Alfresco
- enable DEBUG logs [on Alfresco side](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Log4J_Configuration)
- as far as I can see, ProcessMaker users Alfresco CMIS REST APIs to implement its triggers. Have a look at [`class.pmAlfrescoFunctions.php`](https://github.com/colosa/processmaker/blob/master/workflow/engine/classes/triggers/class.pmAlfrescoFunctions.php) in ProcessMaker and try the calls yourself with some REST client (e.g. [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html), [Chrome REST console](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/rest-console/cokgbflfommojglbmbpenpphppikmonn?hl=en), [htty](https://github.com/htty/htty))

This should give you an idea of what's going wrong in your case.

---

UPDATE

After reading that the Japanese language pack changed a folder name from "Sites" to "/サイト", and double checking the Alfresco triggers [`code`](https://github.com/colosa/processmaker/blob/master/workflow/engine/classes/triggers/class.pmAlfrescoFunctions.php), it's indeed the case that localized versions of Alfresco are not supported OOTB by ProcessMaker, which hardcodes "Sites" in its CMIS queries.

While the [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15261488/350923) provided by [@nmenego](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1160296/nmenego) would be enough in most cases, I opened a [bug](https://github.com/colosa/processmaker/issues/1375) to ProcessMaker to let them know of the limitation.

Comment: Very valid points. I checked all of these points, but for my case, all is well. I have added my answer because for my case, it was what solved the issue. The debug logs in Alfresco as well as the network traffic between the two systems are both OK.

Answer (score 1):

I discovered that the problem was in the encoding used by my installed Alfresco. Instead of the default folder /Sites, the default directory was /サイト (sites in Japanese). Apparently, upon installation, the names of the default folders are translated to Japanese.

What I did was I added a folder named /Sites, and it all works now.
Of course, the points pointed out by skuro are all valid as well.

Comment: IIRC that's an ancient bug, I had troubles with it like three years ago... I forgot to ask, which version of Alfresco are you using?

Comment: I added the versions of Alfresco and ProcessMaker to the original question in case other people encounter this problem. Also, if I could be so bold to ask a favor from you @skuro to edit original tags and add processmaker, since I do not have enough reputations to do so. Thanks!

Comment: Tag added. Apparently the Alf version you're using is pretty new, I'll see if there's any problem on the side of localizations...

Comment: Ok, the problem is indeed in ProcessMaker: the PHP file I linked above hardcodes "Sites" in a couple of places, so that when you localize your Alfresco instance the integration falls apart.

Answer (score 0):

We just confirmed that this is a bug in the ProcessMaker connector triggers for Alfresco, thank you for reporting it.

I've just opened ticket [11003](http://bugs.processmaker.com/view.php?id=11003) in ProcessMaker's Main Support Portal for the developers to work on fixing it.

Please register for free in [ProcessMaker's Main Support Portal](http://bugs.processmaker.com) in order to follow up on the resolution of this bug.

Best regards,

**Arturo A. Robles**
**Customer & Partner Support Manager**
**Colosa Inc. - ProcessMaker**